# issues when getting the value of a variable in php

Tags: php, variables, fpdf

I have this fpdf and I am trying to print a cell only if a variable is equal to 5, then another cell when it is equal to 6. It is a form with questions where students must fill in the right answer.

this prints the rows with A B C D E (answers):

```
if ($row['tipo'] == "sc" OR $row['tipo'] == "sel")
        {
        $array_risposte = array( $row['risposta1'],$row['risposta2'],$row['risposta3'],$row['risposta4'],$row['risposta5'],$row['risposta6'],$row['risposta7'],$row['risposta8'],$row['risposta9'],$row['risposta10']);
        $array_filtrato = array_filter($array_risposte);
        $result2 = count($array_filtrato);


        $letterposition= array (' A',' A',' B',' C',' D',' E',' F',' G',' H',' I',' J');
        $position=1;
        while($position<=$result2)
          {
          $stampanumero = $letterposition[$position].$p->Image($image1, $p->GetX()+6, $p->GetY()+1);
          $p->Cell(14, 6, $stampanumero, 1, 0, 'L');
          //$domande .= $position." [ ] ";

          $position++;
          }
    }
```

It works perfectly. And on top I want to name the coloumns A B C D, and if there is an answer E, to print the coloumn E. (The coloumns ABCD are always there, no issue with that). My code doesn't print coloumn E:

```
if($letterposition[$position]=="5")
{       
$p->Cell(14, 5, $LetterE, 1, 0, 'L','true'); //RISPONSI
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$letterposition is an array which contain the letters array. Actualy the value of $letterposition[$position] will be a letter 'E' not '5'.

Comment: in fact, it is working, I had to add the space before E just like ' E' in the array. Thanks!